# In R, using Ubuntu, try to install a lib depending on GMP C lib, it won't find GMP, but I have GMP installed

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, gmp

I want to install the Rmpfr library of R, so I type within R:

```
install.packages("Rmpfr")
```

This package requires the GMP C library to be installed, which in Ubuntu can be installed typing on the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

So, after I try to install Rmpfr library in R, I receive an error message containing

```
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
```

The problem is, I already have GNU MP installed, and its version is 5.1.2. So, something is wrong with me, maybe.

Any clues? :-)
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? I was just able to install using Saucy. Also have you installed the latest version of libmpfr-dev?

Comment: You can run `./configure` manually and examine `config.log` to see what actually failed.

Comment: I use Saucy. I have the 3.1.1-2 version of libmpfr-dev, which is the last one.

Comment: I ran `./configure` first on the R GMP package, and `config.log` returned this:

configure:534: checking for __gmpz_ui_sub in -lgmp  
configure:553: cc -o conftest   -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c -lgmp   1>&5  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory

Comment: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: failed program was:
#line 542 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h

Answer (score 80):

In my case it was solved by installation of `libgmp3-dev`

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Comment: Yes, this option worked for me as well. I can't imagine life without stackoverflow.

Comment: If you are using CentOS, it will work with `sudo yum install gmp-devel`

Comment: @Marius this also works for Fedora. (Might be obvious for some, but not for everyone)

Comment: solution works for Ubuntu 20.04. Why can't it get accepted?

Answer (score 2):

It worked after I installed `build-essential` and `libboost`. Yes, I had something lacking on my system. :-)

Comment: Installing `build-essential` was enough to fix the problem for me. Thanks!