# Error while installing Rmpfr on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, gmp, mpfr

I am trying to install the R package Rmpfr on Linux Ubuntu and I get the following error message:

```
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rmpfr/libs/Rmpfr.so':
  libmpfr.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I am already aware that similar questions have been asked, but the error message is different and I have tried the suggestion on this post:
[In R, using Ubuntu, try to install a lib depending on GMP C lib, it won't find GMP, but I have GMP installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277440/in-r-using-ubuntu-try-to-install-a-lib-depending-on-gmp-c-lib-it-wont-find-g)

Comment: (this would work on a newer Ubuntu) How are you installing Rmpfr? What did you download from where and which instructions did you follow?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the `libmpfr4` and `libmpfr-dev` packages installed?

```
edd@max:~$ COLUMNS=90 dpkg -l | grep mpfr | cut -c-80
ii  libmpfr-dev:amd6 3.1.1-2       amd64         multiple precision floating-poi
ii  libmpfr4:amd64   3.1.1-2       amd64         multiple precision floating-poi
edd@max:~$
```

You need both `libmpfr4` and `libmpfr-dev`. I am fairly certain that your build failed before the line you showed because 'cannot load' due to a lack of library suggests that the linking, and possibly compilation failed.

You are installing from the `Rmpfr` source package, correct?

Comment: I have libmpfr-dev   2.4.2-3ubuntu1 but I don't have libmpfr4. When I try to install using apt-get I get: E: Package libmpfr4 has no installation candidate

Comment: Yes, I am installing Rmpfr from source. I still haven't managed to install libmpfr4. I am getting a slightly different error message now `*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rmpfr/libs/Rmpfr.so':
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rmpfr/libs/Rmpfr.so: undefined symbol: mpfr_digamma
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
`