# Why does Travis CI fail to build b/c R package is unavailable, while passing devtools::check()?

Tags: r, travis-ci

The package causing the problem is apparently `numbers`. My best guess as to why is because numbers was built under an older version of R (as is indicated by the warning message I get when I `library(numbers)` in R).

But I'm pretty new to Travis CI and R packages in general, so I could be missing something.

[The Travis CI log is here](https://travis-ci.org/rBatt/rbLib/builds/69173770)

I'm confused not only because the R pacakge `numbers` is available to me (OSX), but also because my package passes the `devtools::check()`. My package passed on Travis previously (when it only depended on `ssh.utils`), so I'm pretty sure the problem is somehow related to `numbers`.

Is this Travis error message related to the way I've asked Travis to install a package? Is there a setting I can change in my Travis yml to allow the build to pass? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logs, the package `gmp` install is failing, as Travis systems don't have gmp installed:

```
* installing *source* package ‘gmp’ ...
** package ‘gmp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
creating cache ./config.cache
checking for __gmpz_ui_sub in -lgmp... no
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gmp’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/gmp’
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277440/in-r-using-ubuntu-try-to-install-a-lib-depending-on-gmp-c-lib-it-wont-find-g) here for how to install it, you can probably add the code:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

to your Travis config file (not tested).

Comment: It worked! New logs if anyone interested: https://travis-ci.org/rBatt/rbLib/builds/69190263

Comment: Also, I used that exact code snipper you provided; I put it in the yml under the `before_install:` header (and threw a `- ` in front of what you wrote, as per the yml syntax)